# How to search for Google photo spheres

Tags: google-maps, street-view

Just for fun, I would like to be able to type a city or landmark into one of Google's apps and get a list of interactive photo spheres taken there.

The main site https://www.google.com/streetview/ has a completely random list of locations and as far as I can tell no way to search for what I want. When I look up an area in Google Maps I get a list of 10 pictures, and they are usually not photo spheres. Neither of these is really what I'm looking for.